# Scrollview doesn't scroll in fragment

Tags: java, android, scrollview

UPDATED QUESTION: I'm trying to scroll but don't scroll at all. Check the image:

[image]

OLD:
I have 5 more cardviews inside my linearlayout but I just pasted 1. I don't know what is causing trouble with the scrollview. I already tried removing the first linearlayout but didn't work.

XML:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_nearby_newest"
    xmlns:fresco="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="#fafafa"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
            card_view:contentPadding="10dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin fermentum vulputate finibus. Morbi venenatis blandit purus, sit amet ultricies elit laoreet imperdiet. Morbi suscipit diam non consequat faucibus. Aliquam erat volutpat. Mauris luctus, eros nec mollis dapibus, lorem nunc pharetra arcu, ut rhoncus erat erat sed mi. Morbi condimentum lacinia augue, nec malesuada ligula posuere suscipit. Sed vehicula ex cursus, tempor libero eu, finibus metus."
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
            card_view:contentPadding="10dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin fermentum vulputate finibus. Morbi venenatis blandit purus, sit amet ultricies elit laoreet imperdiet. Morbi suscipit diam non consequat faucibus. Aliquam erat volutpat. Mauris luctus, eros nec mollis dapibus, lorem nunc pharetra arcu, ut rhoncus erat erat sed mi. Morbi condimentum lacinia augue, nec malesuada ligula posuere suscipit. Sed vehicula ex cursus, tempor libero eu, finibus metus."
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
            card_view:contentPadding="10dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin fermentum vulputate finibus. Morbi venenatis blandit purus, sit amet ultricies elit laoreet imperdiet. Morbi suscipit diam non consequat faucibus. Aliquam erat volutpat. Mauris luctus, eros nec mollis dapibus, lorem nunc pharetra arcu, ut rhoncus erat erat sed mi. Morbi condimentum lacinia augue, nec malesuada ligula posuere suscipit. Sed vehicula ex cursus, tempor libero eu, finibus metus."
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
            card_view:contentPadding="10dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin fermentum vulputate finibus. Morbi venenatis blandit purus, sit amet ultricies elit laoreet imperdiet. Morbi suscipit diam non consequat faucibus. Aliquam erat volutpat. Mauris luctus, eros nec mollis dapibus, lorem nunc pharetra arcu, ut rhoncus erat erat sed mi. Morbi condimentum lacinia augue, nec malesuada ligula posuere suscipit. Sed vehicula ex cursus, tempor libero eu, finibus metus."
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin fermentum vulputate finibus. Morbi venenatis blandit purus, sit amet ultricies elit laoreet imperdiet. Morbi suscipit diam non consequat faucibus. Aliquam erat volutpat. Mauris luctus, eros nec mollis dapibus, lorem nunc pharetra arcu, ut rhoncus erat erat sed mi. Morbi condimentum lacinia augue, nec malesuada ligula posuere suscipit. Sed vehicula ex cursus, tempor libero eu, finibus metus."
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Paste code as actual code, not as screenshots

Comment: Screenshots scare away developers.

Comment: I edited my answer

Comment: layout_height is wrapped and you dont have childs in it ? so why Scroll

Comment: Yes I have, but didn't pasted all. I have 5 cardviews inside. layout_height is wrapped, do you mean the first one?

Comment: lol with out showing what you have inside and show a wrap one how come we know what you have ..

Comment: That's why I edited my answers. There is the cardview. I just have 5+ like the one above.

Comment: see my answer below

Answer (score 0):

scroll view does not scroll till its content reaches its parent size

to understand that take a look at this example

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/frame"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        tools:context=".MainActivity"
        tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

// now scroll is 200dp in height 
            <ScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp">
// child of scroll 
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_height="200dp">

//inner children have more height than scroll view height (total 600dp) which made scroll view to scroll 
                <LinearLayout
                    android:background="#000"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="300dp"></LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                            android:background="#0F0"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="300dp"></LinearLayout>

                </LinearLayout>
            </ScrollView>
        </LinearLayout>

    </FrameLayout>
```

Comment: you dont need hardcode values like this but add them to clear the idea in your one scroll view children doen not have enough height to scroll

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is weird, because I hardcode the value like this :    <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="515dp"   and it's working fine, but If I change to match_parent the scroll dont work